# Simulating movement similar to dust particles

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, physics

I've tried a `setInterval` loop with css and animate. Both ways of movement consists of tiny movement from oldpos1 -> newpos1 with no random curve movement, easing however occured with jQuery animate but only between randomly generated 1-3 pixels, which is not what I want
.
Does the problem lies in `setInterval`'s clock, where only linear time units flow?

**Where should I start, to make below images exist in jQuery?**

What I would like to do:

1. Dodge behaviour:

   A, B - particle

   AB1 - common dodge area, only certain amount

[image]

2 Movement:

Av, Bv - random circular movement

Aacc, Bacc - where the tiny random acceleration occurs (on image marked as more condenced dashed lines)

[image]

Comment: You should get paths like that with a randomly changing acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on jQuery's `animate` for this as your case is rather special ... instead, use the "game loop pattern": Have a game object which keeps a collection of particles, which are moved (and collided ...) and then drawn in regular intervals.

Here's a basic structure:

```
function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = 0; // in pixels per second
    this.direction = 0; // in radians per second
}

Particle.prototype.move = function(d_time) {
    this.x += Math.cos(this.direction) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.sin(this.direction) * this.speed;
}

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    // either set the position of a DOM object belonging to this particle
    // or draw to a canvas
}

function Game() {
    this.particles = Array();

    this.MS_PER_FRAME = 20; // in milliseconds
    this.D_TIME = 1000.0 / this.MS_PER_FRAME;
}

Game.prototype.tick = function() {
    $.each(this.particles, function(_, particle) {
        particle.move(this.D_TIME);
        particle.draw();
    })
}

Game.prototype.go = function() {
    setInterval(this.tick, this.MS_PER_FRAME)
})
```

Then you can manipulate speed and direction of particles as you like, maybe by introducing additional members `d_speed` (acceleration) and `d_direction` or so.

Comment: is there any way of making half circle vector path in javascript, then move particle along that path, every time it reaches the end of the path, script adds the same half circle path but leaves randomness into path size, circle flip(if previous path had bezier curve up, then now it will be same or down) ??

Comment: If you take the above framework and add a constant `d_direction` to `direction` every frame/tick, the particle will move in a cirle. If you vary `d_direction` every n milliseconds, you can create more complicated moving patterns like you describe.