# Bouncing Ball, Pendulum or any other Timewise-Incremental-addition system in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, physics

[image]

> **Puzzles**
>
> 1. I cannot understand why the function `+=` result in a bit oscillating -pattern. I expected oscillating pattern needs changing
>      the sign of the addition with `right: '+=50'` but no. I expected
>      something like 100, 150, 200, 250, etc. But it looks like to move like
>      50,0, 50, 0, 50, 0, why?
> 2. How can I create an oscillating dot with something like `+=50/log(time)`?

**TRIAL 1: trying to understand the incremental addition in jQuery**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div { 
background-color:#bca; 
width:100px; 
border:1px solid green;
}
</style>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div    id='ball'
    style='width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; left:10px;'></div>

<script>
    // PASTE T2 or T3 from below.
</script>
</body>
```

**TRIAL 2: button to control the oscillation, why 0-50-0-50-etc?**

```
    /*TODO: automatically trigger*/
    /*TODO: Traversing wave with 50/log(time)*/
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#ball').animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: '+=50',  // I CANNOT UNDERSTAND THIS: functionality and how time?
        right: '+=50',
        height: 'toggle'
      }, 2000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
```

**TRIAL 3: trying to get the code working immediately with setInterval, not sure where delay but anyway burning again i.e. not working...with the below**

```
    while (true)
    {
            setInterval(
                    $('#ball').animate({
                          opacity: 0.25,
                          left: '+=50',
                          right: '+=50',
                          height: 'toggle'
                          }, 5000, function() {
                          // Animation complete.
                          }),
                    10000
                    );
    };
```

*P.s. ...to get test the below things fast, use `$ mkdir scripts; cd scripts; wget http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aepmc/ i dont see the oscillating behavior there with width, just with height and that's because of *height: toggle*

Comment: @guido: what is the command then to do the incremental addition? I updated the q to be more clear. Yes, if I can solve any problem such as pendulum, bounching ball etc -- I have solved the problem with timemise incremental addition, I think. Clarified the q.

Comment: without using setInterval() ?

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) the other day... Might be of some assistance.  Its the jQuery path animation plugin.

Comment: Also perhaps interesting to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306717/simulating-movement-similar-to-dust-particles), not using animate but some `"game loop pattern"`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be something to start with:

```
<div id='ball' style='width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;'>                    
</div>
<script>
    var angle = -180;
    var left = 0;
    var topv = 0;
    function updatePos() {
       angle = angle + 2;
       left += Math.cos(angle/360*Math.PI);
       $('#ball').css('left',left);
       topv += Math.cos(angle/360*Math.PI);
       $('#ball').css('top',topv);    
    }
    setInterval('updatePos()',10);
</script>
```

I used cosine instead of log because you were asking about oscillation, you can easily replace it.

EDIT:
in your last sample, you have a couple of problems:

- you don't need the while loop, `setInterval(callback,interval)` will call your `callback` each `interval` millisecs (and until you stop ot with `clearInterval()`)
- if you use animate, or any function like that, i think you should only rely on that and stay "above" it; or you risk end up interfering or messing with the event queue (yours and the builtin one)

Comment: ...if I can understand the oscillation is done so that you execute the same code as a callback in the animate -command or am I misuderstanding? Now this is apparently what you mean by Callback -queue or?

Comment: by callback i mean the function which is repeatedly run every 10 milliseconds, through `setInterval()`; it is plain javascript, only using jquery for setting ball position with `css()`. jquery `animate()` does pretty much the same, adding some more features (ie you can enqueue animations, use predefined effects (easing) and so on).